# Cannot find Node sdk for React/Node App. How to integrate Amazon pay with React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-pay

I want to add Amazon pay to My react application. How to get the widget in app. I don't find any node module related to amazon api. How to integrate amazon pay with a single page web application built in Reactjs. Even I dont find any api injavascript for amazon API.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to load everything using script tags.

There are two main things to look out for:

1. The button div needs to be mounted before the `showButton()` function is invoked.
2. To respond to the various actions (like `onError` in the button widget), you will need to pass a callback function from your react component.

I've written a [medium post](https://medium.com/@avremelk/amazonpay-react-js-f2c84931f82b) which provides example code.